# Android license check going straight to applicationError(...)

Tags: android, android-lvl

I just implemented the android server check in my app. I am using the StrictPolicy method because I may be just a little bitter from the pirated version have 5X the amount of downloads as the version in the market... Anyway, I coded the method basically verbatim into my source code. However, when I toggle the License Test Response on the developer console to Licensed, I get the unlicensed dialog. However, in the applicationError method, dontAllow() is called and when i comment this line out, the unlicensed dialog does not show. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my MyLicenseCheckerCallback class.

I call doCheck in the onCreate, and again in the onResume.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

    // Construct the LicenseChecker with a Policy.
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
        this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
            new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
            BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY
            );
    doCheck();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ...


private void doCheck() {
    mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
}

private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
    public void allow() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // Should allow user access.
    }

    public void dontAllow() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        //Be as annoying as possible
        illegalDownload = new IllegalDownloadHandler(speedy.this);
        illegalDownload.show();
        illegalDownload.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    Intent goToMarket = null;
                    goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.TimothyMilla.SpeedBoost"));
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                    illegalDownload.dismiss();
                }
        });
        // Should not allow access. An app can handle as needed,
        // typically by informing the user that the app is not licensed
        // and then shutting down the app or limiting the user to a
        // restricted set of features.
        // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
        //showDialog(0);
        //onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dontAllow();
        //when I comment the above line out, the unlicensed dialog is not shown.
    }

    private void displayResult(final String result) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //dontAllow();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's weird. I use exact the same methodology here, except that I customized my LVL library a lot. But I still have a very old version of my app here (which uses basic, stock LVL), and I don't have any problem (just tested!). I also tried putting dontAllow() within applicationError for you, and still no problems. Make sure you're copying your public key correctly... that's my guess for what I can see in your code. Ah... and by the way, I'm also using ServerManagerPolicy (you said strict, but of course your code isn't). Ah... and you're populating deviceId correctly, aren't you?

Comment: Happened to me for a few hours, then started working well. No changes made..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you didn't update my comment, my guesses... make sure you:

1- copied your public key correctly.

2- populated deviceId, as I think you are. Just making sure because your code above is hiding that declaration. But since it would throw compile errors at you, I'm sure you are.

3- changed the response code in the developer console (you said you have).

4- Finally, that you included the proper permissions in the Android manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

Comment: Fixed the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I solved it by placing the permissions before the application definition in android manifest, also be careful with the version of the application, if upload up in the market, you must have the same version.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >......
```