# Android licensing sample returns code 3. What does it mean?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I tried licensing sample. It said "application error=3".
I found the sheet of licensing response codes at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/licensing/licensing-reference.html#server-response-codes), but how does number 3 corresponds to the above list? What does that code mean?

Comment: possibel duplicate of this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526889/android-license-check-going-straight-to-applicationerror

Comment: There is no answaer to my question: what each reponse code means in sample.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Check out source code [com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/source/browse/library/src/com/android/vending/licensing/LicenseValidator.java?r=9cd599d6902d8b9b8311e4ef8dd20dcccb5e7aba):

```
/**
 * Contains data related to a licensing request and methods to verify
 * and process the response.
 */
class LicenseValidator {
  private static final String TAG = "LicenseValidator";

  // Server response codes.
  private static final int LICENSED = 0x0;
  private static final int NOT_LICENSED = 0x1;
  private static final int LICENSED_OLD_KEY = 0x2;
  private static final int ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED = 0x3;
  private static final int ERROR_SERVER_FAILURE = 0x4;
  private static final int ERROR_OVER_QUOTA = 0x5;

  private static final int ERROR_CONTACTING_SERVER = 0x101;
  private static final int ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME = 0x102;
  private static final int ERROR_NON_MATCHING_UID = 0x103;

  ... ...
```

"application error=3" means ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED, check out answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377325/how-do-you-deal-with-licensecheckercallback-error-not-market-managed-error-code) to see how to deal with it.

Comment: But what about apps that are still in development phase? 
Those apps would certainly not be market-managed apps, right?